# Fragmented length prefix causes next data read from buffer use incorrect message length

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, protocol-buffers

I'm one of those guys who come here to find answers to those questions that others have asked, and I think i newer asked anything myself, but after two days searching unsuccessfully I decided that it's time to ask something myself. So here it is...

I have a TCP server and client written in C#, .NET 4, asynchronous sockets using **SocketAsyncEventArgs**. I have a **length-prefixed message framing protocol**. Overall everything works just fine, but one issue keeps bugging me.

Situation is like this (I will use small numbers just as an example):

Lets say Server has a Send buffer length of 16 bytes.
It sends a message which is **6 bytes** long, and prefixes it with **4 bytes** long length prefix. Total message length is 6+4=**10**.

Client reads the data and receives a buffer of 16 bytes length (yes 10 bytes of data and 6 bytes equal to zero).

Received buffer looks like this: **6 0 0 0 56 21 33 1 5 7 0 0 0 0 0 0**

So I read first 4 bytes which is my length prefix, I determine that my message is 6 bytes long, I read it as well and everything is fine so far. Then i have 16-10=**6 bytes left** to read. All of them are zeroes I read 4 of them, since it's my length prefix. So it's a zero length message which is allowed as **keep-alive packet**.

Remaining data to read: **0 0**

Now the issue "kicks in". I got only **2 remaining bytes to read**, they are not enough to complete a **4 byte-long** length prefix buffer. So I read those 2 bytes, and wait for more incoming data. Now server is not aware that I'm still reading length prefix (I'm just reading all those zeroes in the buffer) and sends another message correctly prefixed with 4 bytes. And the client is assuming the server sends those missing 2 bytes. I receive the data on the client side, and read first two bytes to form a complete 4 byte length buffer. The results are something like that

lengthBuffer = new byte[4]{**0, 0, 42, 0**}

Which then translates into **2752512** message length. So my code will continue to read next **2752512** bytes to complete the message...

So in every single message framing example I have seen zero length messages are supported as keep-alive's. And every example I've seen doesn't do anything more than I do. The problem is that I do not know how much data I have to read when I receive it from the server. Since I have partially-filled buffer with zeroes, I have to read it all as those zeroes could be keep-alive's I sent from the other end of connection.

I could drop zero-length messages and stop reading the buffer after first empty message and it should fix this issue, and use custom messages for my keep-alive mechanism. But I want to know if I am missing something, or doing something wrong, since every code example I've seen seems to have same issue (?)

**UPDATE**

Marc Gravell, you sir pulled words out of my mouth. Was about to update that the issue is with sending the data. The problem is that initially when exploring .NET Sockets and SocketAsyncEventArgs I came across this sample: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nclsamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=socket%20performance
It uses reusable pool of buffers. Simply takes predefined number of maximum client connections allowed, for example 10, takes maximum single buffer size, for example 512, and creates one large buffer for all of them. So 512 * 10 * 2 (for send and receive) = 10240
So we have byte[] buff = new byte[10240];
Then for each client that connects it assigns a piece of this large buffer. First connected client gets first 512 bytes for Data Reading operations, and gets next 512 bytes (offset 512) for Data Sending operations. Therefore the code ended up having already allocated Send buffer which size is 512 (exactly the number the client later receives as BytesTransferred). This buffer is populated with data, and all remaining space out of these 512 bytes is sent as zeroes.

Strange enough this example is from msdn. The reason there is a single huge buffer is to avoid fragmented heap memory, when buffer gets pinned and GC cant collect it or something like that.

Comment from BufferManager.cs in the provided example (see link above):

> This class creates a single large buffer which can be divided up and
>   assigned to SocketAsyncEventArgs objects for use with each socket I/O
>   operation.  This enables bufffers to be easily reused and gaurds
>   against fragmenting heap memory.

So the issue is pretty much clear. Any suggestions on how I should resolve this are welcome :) Is it true what they say about fragmented heap memory, is it OK to create a data buffer "on the fly"? If so, will I have memory issues when the server scales to a few hundred or even thousands of clients?

Comment: "every code example I've seen seems to have same issue" - not *once* have I seen this issue, *as long as* the reader correctly interprets `BytesTransferred`, and the sender correctly specifies the buffer fragment(s) to be sent. I strongly suspect a bug in your send/receive code - can you post any of it?

Comment: Probably because I was paying all the attention to the receiving end, when the problem is sending the data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds simply like a bug in either your send or receive code. You should **only** get `BytesTransferred` as the data that was actually sent, or some number smaller than that if arriving in fragments. The first thing I would wonder is: did you setup the *send* correctly? i.e. if you have an oversized buffer, a correct implementation might look like:

```
args.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, actualBytesToSend);
if (!socket.SendAsync(args)) { /* whatever */ }
```

where `actualBytesToSend` can be much less than `buffer.Length`. My initial suspicion is that 
you are doing something like:

```
args.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

and therefore sending more data than you have actually populated.

I should emphasize: there is something wrong in either your send or receive; I do not believe, at least without an example, that there is some fundamental underlying bug in the BCL here - I use the async API extensively, and it works fine - but you *do* need to accurately track the data you are sending and receiving at all points.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that you are treating the trailing zeros in the buffer you read as data. This is not data. It is garbage. No one ever sent it to you.

The `Stream.Read` call returns you the number of bytes actually read. You should not interpret the rest of the buffer in any way.

> The problem is that I do not know how much data I have to read when I
>   receive it from the server.

Yes, you do: Use the return value from `Stream.Read`.

Comment: I mentioned that I am using SocketAsyncEventArgs. So all I have is:
SocketAsyncEventArgs e; e.Buffer and e.BytesTransferred.
e.Buffer is a byte array, the one that is partially-filled with zeroes. and e.BytesTransferred is ALWAYS equal to the size of the buffer the server sent to me (NOT the size of actual data, but length of the buffer). Thaths how I end up knowing only that I have to read e.BytesTransferred from e.Buffer which then results in reading all those zeroes.

Comment: Ok, that is not how `BytesTransferred` *should* work (according to the docs and to my understanding). Could you post some code how you use the Receive function and what the callback looks like? If `BytesTransferred` works as you describe it there would indeed be no way to use a Socket reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

> "Now server is not aware that I'm still reading length prefix (I'm just reading all those zeroes in the buffer) and sends another message correctly prefixed with 4 bytes.".

Why? How does the server know what you are and aren't reading? If the server retransmits any part of a message it is in error. TCP already does that for you.

There seems to be something radically wrong with your server.

Comment: No, the server doesn't know anything about what I'm reading. The point is, I am reading all those trailing zeroes as data, because they might be keep-alive's (even though they aren't). The server just sends another message, but the client assumes that it has received only a part of length prefix and waits for 2 more bytes.

Comment: @Marius So you must be reading beyond the end of the data received, which would happen if you ignore the count returned by the read() API. Or else you aren't sending what you think you're sending.

Comment: Updated the question above. I only have SocketAsyncEventArgs.BytesTransferred which is always equal to the size of the buffer that the server sent to me. The issue is on the server side, it seems. I send buffer which is larger than the data itself, therefore the buffer on the receiving end (client) contains data AND zeroes. P.S. I do not have access to read() API. SocketAsyncEventArgs wraps all that inside.